# Including PHP file in a bootstrap application

Tags: php, html, smarty

Hello I am working with a bootstrap project. I have never done this before. But it appears that the html files are using brackets with short PHP. For example in one of my HTML files..

```
 {if isset($errorCaptcha)}
```

Here is the full index file: http://pastebin.com/qWkJfY8v

On top, it calls my header.php. However it does not display my header.php properly My header consists of...

```
<?php 

define('IN_MYBB', 1); require ".../global.php"; 

eval("\$header = \"".$templates->get("header")."\";"); 

output_page($header);

?>
```

The header.php can be accessed directly and display the correct contents. But if I run my index.html file should include that all I get is some text reading...

```
get("header")."\";"); output_page($header); ?>
```

This is displayed on top of the page where the header should appear.

My question is.. Should I be using another line of code in my index.html to call the header?

Answer (score 0):

When including PHP file in Smarty you use [{include_php}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.php.tpl). By using {include} you are including the contents of the PHP file and not processing it.

The line should be:

```
{include_php file="header.php"}
```

I would not recommend including a PHP file straight in the Smarty though. The preferable method is to assign the header or header variables in PHP and then render them in the template.

Comment: that line is no longer in use with Smarty v3. Also, I have never used smarty. is there a quick tutorial on how to assign the header variables and then render them?

Comment: The full documentation is here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/

On the PHP side you should have a Smarty object, you assign variables there with $smarty->assign('variable_name', 'variable_value'); and then use it in the template with {$variable_name}